# SQLiteException: no such table exists Error keeps occurring

Tags: android, database, sqlite

please disregard my inexperience as this is the first time using this and extremely new to coding but I keep getting this error:

" Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: photo (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM photo)"

Please help!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.util.Log;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBController  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String LOGCAT = null;

    public DBController(Context applicationcontext) {
        super(applicationcontext, "androidsqlite.db", null, 1);
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String query;
        query = "CREATE TABLE photo ( photoId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, photoName TEXT)";
        database.execSQL(query);
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"photo Created");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
        String query;
        query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS photo";
        database.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(database);
    }

    public void insertPhoto (HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("photoName", queryValues.get("photoName"));
        database.insert("photo", null, values);
        database.close();
    }

    public int updatePhoto (HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();    
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("photoName", queryValues.get("photoName"));
        return database.update("photo", values, "photoId" + " = ?", new String[] { queryValues.get("photoId") });
        //String updateQuery = "Update  words set txtWord='"+word+"' where txtWord='"+ oldWord +"'";
        //Log.d(LOGCAT,updateQuery);
        //database.rawQuery(updateQuery, null);
        //return database.update("words", values, "txtWord  = ?", new String[] { word });
    }

    public void deletePhoto(String id) {
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"delete");
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();    
        String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM  photo where photoId='"+ id +"'";
        Log.d("query",deleteQuery);     
        database.execSQL(deleteQuery);
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllPhoto() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
        wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM photo";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("photoId", cursor.getString(0));
                map.put("photoName", cursor.getString(1));
                wordList.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return wordList;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getPhotoInfo(String id) {
        HashMap<String, String> wordList = new HashMap<String, String>();
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM photo where photoId='"+id+"'";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                    //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                wordList.put("photoName", cursor.getString(1));
                   //wordList.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }                   
    return wordList;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you get "photo Created" in LogCat before calling `getAllPhoto`?

Comment: Not an answer. Just to notify **another issue**: `String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM  photo where photoId='"+ id +"'";` is wrong: id is an integer, it doesn't want the **'** surrounding its value.

Comment: Just uninstall your app from device or emulator and again install the app and then try, may this will work

Comment: TwisteRob: i dont believe so

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
before this line please initialize first your database

use below line to initialize database

```
SQLiteDatabase database = new SQLiteDatabase ();
```

in your case it will be `DBController  database = new DBController  ();`

```
 DBController   database = getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: I tried still no success...unless I'm inputting it incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

I am using this below method for checking the method for Sqlite table. If table is not there then create it. You have to handle this in your case -

```
public boolean isTableExists(String tableName, boolean openDb) {
    if(openDb) {
        if(mDatabase == null || !mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            mDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
        }

        if(!mDatabase.isReadOnly()) {
            mDatabase.close();
            mDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
        }
    }

    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
                            cursor.close();
            return true;
        }
                    cursor.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Do I add that snippet to my code?